# Best method to create a pipeline of java projects

Tags: java

I am a chemist, and I inherited a large number of java projects that all string together for a data processing protocol. The issue is, currently these are all separate projects, so the user imports their data to one project, waits for the output, and then manually imports that output to another program. My vision is to create a program with a GUI where the user can basically decide which projects they want to run, build a "pipeline" of actions, import their data, and walk away. The issue is, while I know how to code, I have never built something at all like this. I would love if someone could point me to some tutorials, resources, or has any ideas of how to go about doing something like this.

Comment: Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm

Comment: This is a very open ended question. Are you expecting it all to run on a single machine, once? Are you expecting to be able to run the processing in parallel at scale?

You might look at Spark as a hugely scalable solution to the latter. For running a simple pipeline, you might look at setting things up where the stdin of one application uses the data from the stdout of another. Like chaining Unix commands. 

e.g. cat "hello" | grep "h" | wc- l

This won't give you a GUI, but it'll still be easy!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you start those java applications like this currently:

```sh
java -jar project1.jar -outputfile project1.txt
java -jar project2.jar -inputfile project1.txt -outputfile project2.txt
```

The output of one application is the input for the next one.

If you look into those projects, they all have a class with a main method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  File outputFile1 = executeProject1(args[0]);
  //write file to filesystem
  ...
}
```

Now your goal is to get everything into one application, therefore you could create a new Java Application which encapsulates the code of the other projects, e.g.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  File outputFile1 = executeProject1(args[0]);
  //write file to filesystem
  File outputFile2 = executeProject2(outputFile1.getPath());
  ...
```

Since you're thinking about creating a GUI, you want to execute those methods (`executeProjectX(...)`) when clicking a button and providing parameters through GUI input fields. [Java Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) is easy to start with.

This is just a broad idea.
Otherwise you need provide more information.
Which build tool will be used (maven, gradle, ant)? What are the inputs/outputs of the java projects?